# How to move files and folders with Gedit?

Tags: linux, ide, gedit

Is there a plugin or something to be able to drag and drop files in the file browser?

I thought gedit was gonna become my default "IDE" after throwing away Netbeans. But just now I found I can't copy/move files and directories, which is very annoying.

I also tried Geany, and couldn't find this feature either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: gedit is a text editor, not a file manager.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Neither is Netbeans or any other IDE, yet you can move files

Comment: I don't understand, you seem to be trying to make coffee using the dishwasher.

Comment: @terdon Have you ever used an IDE? You can move files around in the file browser, usually in the sidebar. It's *very* useful. Another example: this is not a blog, yet here we are leaving comments. Normally, comments won't answer the question, but they can help.

Comment: Fair enough, fair enough, I'm one of those weird emacs geeks who likes to do everything from the command line :). Have you tried eclipse? It might do what you want. And, of course, you can do this in emacs. You can do *everything* in emacs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this can't be done.

The closest option is to right click on a folder > view folder, and move the files with nautilus.

Answer (score 4):

In gedit, you are able to change the directory of a file or folder the same way as Sublime text editor.. you move it by renaming it with the new directory. For example:

- I have a file located @ www/test.php
- I also have a folder located @ www/test/
- I want my test.php file in the 'test' folder:

### Procedure

1. Right click and rename test.php in gedit file browser sidebar to test/test.php
   This will move the file to the folder you are wanting.
2. Right-click -> Refresh view

You're golden.

Comment: This is a clumsy method, but a clever hack.  :)

Answer (score -1):

It is kinda... Well... Not proper. (as in not a plugin).

1) Click File -> Open

2) Locate directory

3) Drag and Drop file into any folder within that directory.

or

Ctrl + x (cut), Ctrl + c (copy), Ctrl + v (paste) or just use right click menu. Now move to the other directory and paste it.